# Count function not returning 0 count for null values in group by mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

My query like this

```
SELECT 
    rc.id as id,
    rc.name AS categoryName,
    count(r.category) AS raveCount
FROM
    rave r
        LEFT JOIN
    rave_category rc ON (r.category = rc.id)
WHERE
    r.sent_by = 1
GROUP BY rc.id;
```

Here i attached both table structure

[image: rave table]

[image: rave category table]

but answer not returning 0 th values for other category names

[image]

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: This query is a not amazing.  Right now you are, for some reason, trying to output your `rc.id` which is distinct for every record and ALSO trying to group by. What do you expect mysql to spit up for your `rc.id` for the one record it's going to return? Please share your desired results (the result set you want to get from this query) and we can help write it.

Comment: You can use IFNULL(expr1, 0) if you want to return zero instead of NULL

Comment: I'm fighting a losing battle here, but if you have fields that are a more granular level than your GROUP BY you are going to get bad results from this query, or if you are on 5.7+ with default mysql settings you are going to get an error. This would be a good time to learn about how GROUP BY functions and to future proof your query. Perhaps what you are after is something like `SELECT count(rc.id) as raveCount, rc.name as categoryname FROM rave r LEFT JOIN rave_category rc on r.category = rc.id WHERE sent_by = 1 GROUP BY rc.name;` Give that a spin.

Answer (score 1):

If I've got your goal correctly, you just need to switch left and right tables to opposite.

```
SELECT 
    rc.id as id,
    rc.name AS categoryName,
    count(r.category) AS raveCount
FROM rave_category rc
LEFT JOIN rave r
ON r.category = rc.id
  AND r.sent_by = 1
GROUP BY rc.id;
```

Comment: @Musni You dont need tag the user on his own response, he will get notification anyway. If this solve your problem consider accept this answer as correct using the green tick

Answer (score 0):

`r.category` is in the left table. It will not have `null` values (due to non-matching records) post the `Left Join`. You need to count `rc.id`, so that it counts it as zero, where there is no matching entry in the rightmost table.

Also, you should mention all the `select` columns (except aggregated expressions) in the Group by.

Also, you need to Select `r.category` from the leftmost table. And, I have changed alias to `cat_id` to make it unambiguous.

Try:

```
SELECT 
    r.category AS cat_id,
    rc.name AS categoryName,
    count(rc.id) AS raveCount
FROM
    rave r
        LEFT JOIN
    rave_category rc ON (r.category = rc.id)
WHERE
    r.sent_by = 1
GROUP BY cat_id, 
         categoryName
```

Comment: Get `rc.id as id` out of that SELECT though. For goodness sakes. Mysql will just spit a random one back or error depending on OPs version. Add `categoryName` to the group by as well.

Comment: @JNevill please check I am doing the same only. I am not just reusing alias names.

Comment: You are not doing the same only. You literally have the field `rc.id` present in your SELECT. Given OP's sample data and how it's written to disk and how innoDB feels like retrieving from disk it's going to spit up either '2', '3', or '4' none of which make sense for a return on an aggregation...or, if OP is on mysql 5.7+ with default settings this query will error out.

Answer (score 0):

use `ifnull` function in case of null it will return 0

```
SELECT 
    rc.id as id,
    rc.name AS categoryName,
    IFNULL(count(r.category),0) AS raveCount
FROM
    rave r
        LEFT JOIN
    rave_category rc ON (r.category = rc.id)
WHERE
    r.sent_by = 1
GROUP BY rc.id,rc.name;
```

Comment: `COUNT()` never return null. And doesnt count null. The problem is the count is 3 when he is expecting 0